# Histogram after thresholding

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram

I have an image and I apply thresholding to it to apply binary mask.I draw histogram before and after the thresholding process.The histograms look like below.

[image: Histgram before thresholding][image: Histgram after thresholding]

The second figure which is after thresholding,doesn't show any peaks.Is that mean,my thresholding is wrong.Can anyone please explain these histograms.

**Update**

Image after thresholding

[image: Updated image]

Comment: In the second figure, do you see that blue color rising from bottom to top of `0` an `1`? it is telling you  something !  Write`xlim([-0.5 1.5])` after that figure to visualize

Comment: okey,thank you.Now I can see those peaks,but can you explain these histograms,i need to know about these briefly

Answer (score 2):

To summarize Sardar's comment, the horizontal range of your plot is tight.  Simply loosen the range a bit so you can see the result better.  Doing `xlim([-0.5 1.5]);` will certainly do that and we can see that in the last figure of your update.  How you interpret the histogram... well, for black and white images, examining the histogram is never meaningful because there are only two possible intensities to examine - 0 and 1. Histograms usually give a glimpse as to the contrast of the image.  If the histogram is spread out, this usually gives an indication that the image has high contrast.  However, if the histogram is within a small range this usually means the image is poor contrast.

Remember that the histogram simply count the occurrence of instances in a data set.  In this case, we are counting how many times we see 0 and 1 in the image.  Referring to your last plot, this means that approximately 9000 pixels that are intensity 0 and approximately 4000 pixels that are intensity 1.  This gives absolutely no indication as to the contrast or the spread of the intensities in your image. because there are only two possible intensities that are seen in the image.  As such, to answer your question in such a long-winded way, the answer is that you can't really interpret anything.

The only thing I can possible suggest is that it tells you the ratio of object pixels to background pixels and could indicate a measure of quality.  Usually when we determine what is an object and what are background pixels, we would expect that there would be more background pixels than object pixels to be able to discern this from the background.  Therefore, the more black pixels you have the better it may be.  That being said, I can't really say more unless you actually show us what your image looks like after you threshold it.